# how can i know postdelayed has finished its operation in android

Tags: android, handler

I have a Handler how can i know when the postdelayed method has been completed.

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            ll.setEnabled(false);
        } 
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can always write one `flag/toast/log` in that run() method like,

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ 
            public void run() { 
                ll.setEnabled(false); 
                handler.postDelayed(afterExe,0);
            }  
        }, 3000);   

Runnable afterExe = new Runnable()
{
   public void run()
   {
           //code to next step
   }
}
```

Sorry If i didn't get you correctly.

Comment: Its not user the user who wants to know, but for program to know that this operation has been completed and next operation should be started.

Comment: what is the difference between question code and answer code.

Comment: Thanks, i think the page to a while to refresh.

Comment: @VDroid so now you got the answer?